# Handling slashes in parameters for URI using Restlet 2.1.1

Tags: restlet-2.0

I have a URI like this:
     `http://localhost:8111/myService/{Param1}/{Param2}/Param3`

Param1, Param2, Param3 may or may not contains special characters such as #, &, @, /

I am having the clients encode these special characters such as using %2F for /

On the restlet side I am then using string replace to decode these characters.
`param2.replaceAll("%2F", "/")`

Is there a better way to do this to auto interpret these encoded characters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following seems to have taken care of it for me ...

`(Reference.decode((String)request.getAttributes().get("Param2")))`